# Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight - Toast Notification Launch Causes App to Restart

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I'm working on Toast Notifications for my WP8.1 Silverlight App that are activated via a background process.  Whenever I tap on the Toast when it appears (or tap on it from the Notification Action Center), it always restarts the app. It navigates to the main page for a split-second and I notice that the Bing Map I have embedded in the Mainpage is blank, then it restarts.  I specify in the toast for it to go to the mainpage as follows (with a parameter):

```
((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", "#/MainPage.xaml?conversation=12345");
```

Other aberrant behavior is

- When debugging, and the app is invoked from the Toast the main page 'onNavigatedTo' event gets hit twice both times with the parameter specified from the toast.
- When the app relaunches itself after being invoked from the Toast, and I go back to the Start Screen and tap the Live Tile to be taken back to the app, it again needs to restart itself. This never happens if I launch the app normally from the Live Tile or Application Icon.

The debugger isn't catching anything. Could it be something to do with the app being tombstoned, or the app 'Applicated_Activated' event not being hit up properly?

Comment: I could get it to work on a 'Hello World' Silverlight app. But not on my one. I wasn't able to figure how why it wouldn't work on mine, so I just had to leave that feature out.

Comment: Weird @kernanb. I wasn't even able to do that with a background task. I made a dummy MyTask with a timer and anytime it hit, it would hit twice on NavigatedTo. The first time had nothing and the second time has the data in it.